# Amending two previous commits in a pull request with a code cleanup

Tags: git, git-commit

I've made a pull request to a git repo on github. The pull request consists of changes to three files:

1. commit #34a3f04 - Creates a file with a new test for the patch
2. commit #e6298db - the actual patch to the code
3. *commit #49090b3 - changelog commit

   - commit #3 is where HEAD is on my local repo.

So I screwed up and forgot to tidy up my code. So the #1 and #2 commits failed the Travis test.

I have since tidied up the code in the two files on my local repo. Now I want to figure out how to commit these cleanly back into the pull request. I think I have to amend the previous two commits but I'm not quite sure what the best way to pull this off is. I'm sure I will screw it up and cause myself an hour of headaches and I'm hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Either close this PR and open a new one, amend the broken commits and push with `--force` if possible but in that case at least inform other people who have already pulled the PR or push the next two fixed commits on top of the previous 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a rebase here in order to modify history, or squash your commits. You have a couple of options I can see for this:

#### Rebase and use "edit" to amend your commits

The description of "edit": `e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending`. You could use this to go back to fix your linting or whatever on commit 2 and 3, which would then include them in those commits again.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
# use "e" or "edit" for commits 1 and 2
# adjust them as necessary, then git rebase --continue each time
```

#### Squash everything into one

You lose the granularity of your commit messages, but this is also a quick and easy way to solve your problem.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
# choose "s" or "squash", or "f" or "fixup" which is like squash but discards commit
# messages
```

You can also `git reset target-branch-name` which will do a soft reset, keeping all of your changes between your branch and `target-branch-name` but resetting your commits. You could then fix up all your code together and re-commit them as you wish.

---

All of these suggestions require a force push since you've rewritten the history of your local branch.

Comment: OK, so the files I fixed have not been committed or added to the repo. Do I commit those both together in a new commit and then do the rebase?

Comment: Yes, or you can add them to one of your old commits while you rebase and "edit" older commits. If you use the soft reset option you don't need to commit them at all, they'll just become part of your unstaged changes like everything else.